# Remove hyphen from duration format time

Tags: bash, sed

I need to remove hyphen from duration format time and i didn't succeed with sed command as i intended to do it.

**original output:**

```
00:0-26:0-8
00:0-28:0-30
00:0-28:0-4
00:0-28:0-28
00:0-27:0-54
00:0-27:0-19
```

**Expected output:**

```
00:26:08
00:28:30
00:28:04
00:28:28
00:27:54
00:27:19
```

I tried with command but i am stucked.

```
sed 's/;/ /g' temp_file.txt  | awk '{print $8}' | grep - | sed 's/-//g;s/00:0/0:/g'
```

Comment: It would be better if you posted the initial `temp_file.txt` fragment. I think your current pipeline could be significantly optimized

Answer (score 3):

Using `sed`:

```
sed 's/\<[0-9]\>/0&/g;s/:00-/:/g' file
```

The first command `s/\<[0-9]\>/0&/g` is adding a zero to single digit numbers.

The second command `s/:00-/:/g` is removing the `0-` in front of the number.

Answer (score 2):

With your shown sample only, following `awk` may help you on same.

```
awk -F":" '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){sub(/0-/,"",$i);$i=length($i)==1?0$i:$i}} 1' OFS=":"  Input_file
```

In case you want to save output into Input_file itself then append `> temp_file && mv temp_file Input_file` to above command too.

Answer (score 1):

For the given example, this one-liner does the job:

```
awk -F':0-' '{printf "%02d:%02d:%02d\n",$1,$2,$3}' file
```

Answer (score 0):

If I have the below output with two columns "duration time"? When I try to use one of your regexp above is adding me "0" for the first column duration time/timestamp and I dont want that, just the column $7 = duration_time separated by **;** to be modified.

```
01;12May2018 8:20:36;192.168.1.111;78787;192.168.1.111;78787;80:25:0-49;2018-05-12_111111;RO
02;14May2018 2:43:16;192.168.1.132;78787;192.168.1.111;78787;36:10:0-10;2018-05-12_111111;RO
03;15May2018 7:40:01;192.168.131.1;78787;192.168.1.111;78787;18:39:0-44;2018-05-12_111111;RO
04;15May2018 12:37:46;192.168.1.201;78787;192.168.1.111;78787;12:51:0-14;2018-05-12_111111;RO
```

Here is the output:

```
root@root> sed 's/\<[0-9]\>/0&/g;s/:00-/:/g' temp_file
01;12May2018 08:20:36;192.168.01.111;78787;192.168.01.111;78787;80:25:49;2018-05-12_111111;RO
02;14May2018 02:43:16;192.168.01.132;78787;192.168.01.111;78787;36:10:10;2018-05-12_111111;RO
03;15May2018  07:40:01;192.168.131.01;78787;192.168.01.111;78787;18:39:44;2018-05-12_111111;RO
04;15May2018 12:37:46;192.168.01.201;78787;192.168.01.111;78787;12:51:14;2018-05-12_111111;RO
```